# Despliegue de carpetas proyecto C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, desarrollo

Tengo una gran duda o confusión al respecto de las carpetas que dependen de la aplicación y su utilización tanto en modo Desarrollo como en Producción.

Bien, intento explicar mi problemática o duda.

En desarrollo hay una serie de carpetas que luego se encapsulan en el exe final, por ejemplo Recursos, Forms, etc. No hay problema con éstas.

En cambio, tengo una llamada OutputFiles que es una carpeta que se crea al ejecutar el programa. Cuando estoy en desarrollo se ejecuta dentro de la ruta correspondiente al proyecto y dentro de la carpeta bin\Debug, pero me gustaría que se creara en la raíz del proyecto.

Mediante `_OUTPUT_FILES_PATH = GetOutputFilesPath();` recupero la ruta tal que así

```
private string GetOutputFilesPath()
{
    if (isDevelopPath())
        return Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName, "OutputFiles");

    return Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "OutputFiles");

}

private bool isDevelopPath()
{
    if (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Contains("Debug"))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Funcionar de momento funciona, pero me gustaría saber si es la manera habitual de proceder en un entorno más profesional y en caso que no lo fuese, indicarme qué tendría que cambiar.

Saludos.

Comment: porque en la raiz de tu proyecto? y cuando estes en produccion, donde queres que este???  o sea, que te molesta que este en bin/debug, si ese es el lugar donde esta tu exe y es el path de ejecucion?

Comment: ¿Qué pasaría si tu aplicación está en la raíz de una unidad cualquiera? Probablemente una excepción.

Comment: @gbianchi, en cierto modo sí, para acceder a esos ficheros para ir viendo si están escritos bien y tal, acabo antes si la tengo en la misma carpeta del proyecto y no tan "hacia abajo"

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, pues esa opción no me la había planteado, pero supuestamente cuando genere el instalador la enviaré a alguna carpeta de Archivos de Programa. Realmente no sé si podría darse el caso que tu comentas si hago lo que estoy diciendo.

Comment: Es que, eso, es una excusa muyyyyyy mala. La carpeta va donde tiene que ir, siempre.. cuando publiques la app, la carpeta ira dentro de donde esta el programa, o donde la mandes.. no en el raiz... esto no es comodidad... porque la podrias tener abierta en otro lado y chau problema..

Answer (score 0):

Pasa que `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` retorna el directorio de trabajo. Supongamos que la aplicación se llama `app.exe` y se encuentra instalada en la ruta `c:\aplicacion\app.exe`. Ahora abres la consola y colocas

```
> cd c:\aplicacion
> app.exe
```

Es decir, entras en la carpeta y ejecutas la aplicación, el `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` retornará `c:\aplicacion` (como sería lo lógico). No obstante, ahora prueba ejecutar la aplicación desde otra ruta, digamos `c:\`

```
> cd c:\
> c:\aplicacion\app.exe
```

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` retornará `c:\`, porque estamos ejecutando desde esa carpeta. Esto es lo que te sucede, visual estudio cambia la carpeta de ejecución entre el `release` y el `debug`. Esto Tambien puede traer problemas en producción, ya que nada asegura el desde donde un tercero ejecute la aplicación.

Por tanto, yo prefiero utilizar:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location)
```

El cual te dará una ruta constante, no importante desde donde se ejecute la aplicación, esto a través de localizar la dll de la misma.

Comment: Pero su codigo esta bien.. su problema es otro...